# RSpec type request and jb gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec to test my API. For creating the response of an get request I'm using the jb gem.

Example:

```
RSpec.describe 'Tax Invoice API', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /tax_invoice' do

    context('when request is valid') {
      it 'get pending tax invoice' do
        invoice = FactoryBot.create(:invoice)
        get "/tax_invoice/#{invoice.extern_orderno}"
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def show
   @invoice = Invoice.where(extern_orderno: params['id'])&.first
end
```

view(show.json.jb):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
{
    extern_orderno: params['id'],
    status: @invoice.nil? ? 'NOT_AVAILABLE' : @invoice.status,
    url: @invoice&.url,
    created_at: @invoice&.created_at,
    address: @invoice&.address&.to_hash,
    postal_address: @invoice&.postal_address&.to_hash
}.compact
```

The construct works fine expect the test doesn't work. I getting always:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat: TaxInvoiceController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []
```

when I call the test. Someone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Invoice.find_by(extern_orderno: params['id'])`. You really got to stop abusing the safe navigation operator - this is just going to bury a bunch of bugs everywhere. If `@invoice` is nil you should not be rendering the JSON in the first place. Return `head :404` instead and do some proper error handling in your ajax handler.

Answer (score 1):

Set format explicitly in your test request - otherwise it's set to default of `html`:

```
     it 'get pending tax invoice' do
        invoice = FactoryBot.create(:invoice)
        get "/tax_invoice/#{invoice.extern_orderno}", format: :json # <<<<<<<<<
        # ...
    end
```

Comment: I tried this, howevery the get command doesn't accept the format argument. :(  --> ArgumentError: unknown keyword: format

Comment: try to add it explicitly: `get "/tax_invoice/#{invoice.extern_orderno}.json"`

Comment: Didn't work either. Got the unknown format exception.

Comment: OK, found it - you need to set proper headers, [see the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response). Please check if it works and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yep, I set the headers, but I got the same exception. When I called the API outside tests, I doesn't send an application header with the get request. But then, it works. It works not only for the RSpec tests...

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you're requests are in JS or in some other format, i haven't taken a look but its the following for JS:

```
         get "/tax_invoice/#{invoice.extern_orderno}", xhr:true
```

for a different format, place:

```
         get "/tax_invoice/#{invoice.extern_orderno}", format:json
```

Note that  if not specified it uses a html default , which is causing your error.

See [link](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-xhr-ajax-requests) for more info.